# Python: Why is comparison between lists and tuples not supported?

Tags: python, list, comparison, tuples

When comparing a tuple with a list like ...

```
>>> [1,2,3] == (1,2,3)
False
>>> [1,2,3].__eq__((1,2,3))
NotImplemented
>>> (1,2,3).__eq__([1,2,3])
NotImplemented
```

... Python does not deep-compare them as done with `(1,2,3) == (1,2,3)`.

So what is the reason for this? Is it because the mutable list can be changed at any time (thread-safety issues) or what?

(I know where this is implemented in CPython, so please don't answer *where*, but *why* it is implemented.)

Comment: A list is not a tuple and vice versa. They are different types.  `[] == ()` will return `False`.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12135264/what-are-the-best-ways-to-compare-the-contents-of-two-list-like-objects/12135322#12135322

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can always "cast" it

```
>>> tuple([1, 2]) == (1, 2)
True
```

Keep in mind that Python, unlike for example Javascript, [is strongly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strongly_typed_programming_language) [typed](http://wiki.python.org/moin/Why%20is%20Python%20a%20dynamic%20language%20and%20also%20a%20strongly%20typed%20language), and some (most?) of us prefer it that way.

Comment: I like to think that most of us prefer it that way.

Comment: I think the idea of strong typing is what really matters here, so I'll accept your answer as correct.

Comment: Types is types.  Just because list and tuple are both "sequences" doesn't really mean much.  You can't compare a file and a tuple, and they're also both iterable sequences.

Comment: Although 1 == 1.0 even though they are different types.

Comment: @Paul Hankin: Coercion rules are an odd thing.  Arithmetic coercion is marginally tolerable.  More complex, non-scalar type conversion is almost impossible to justify because of the ad-hoc rules that have to get invented.

Comment: @S.Lott And what about str/unicode or set/frozenset? Isn't the relation between set and frozenset exactly the same as that between list and tuple?

Comment: Strong typing has nothing to do with it. In Python, the int 4 and the float 4.0 have different types, but are considered to represent the same *value,* and so they compare as equal. Clojure is also a strongly-typed language, and it considers the sequence '(1 2 3) and the vector [1 2 3] to have the same value, despite being of different types - they're different internal representations of the same data. Python happened to choose a computationally faster and easier-to-implement approach to collection equality. But neither approach is more "strongly typed" than the other.

Answer (score 14):

There's no technical reason for lists not being able to compare to tuples; it's entirely a design decision driven by semantics.  For proof that it's not related to thread-safety, you can compare lists to other lists:

```
>>> l1 = [1, 2, 3]
>>> l2 = [1, 2, 3]
>>> l1 == l2
True
>>> id(l1) == id(l2)
False
```

It seems reasonable to allow users to directly compare lists and tuples, but then you end up with other questions: should the user be allowed to compare lists and queues?  What about any two objects which provide iterators?  What about the following?

```
>>> s = set([('x', 1), ('y', 2)])
>>> d = dict(s)
>>> s == d  # This doesn't work
False
```

It can get complicated pretty quickly.  The language designers recognized the issue, and avoided it by simply preventing different collection types from comparing directly with each other<sup>1</sup>.

Note that the simple solution (to create a new list from the tuple and compare them) is easy but inefficient.  If you're working with large numbers of items, you're better off with something like:

```
def compare_sequences(iter1, iter2):
    iter1, iter2 = iter(iter1), iter(iter2)
    for i1 in iter1:
        try:
            i2 = next(iter2)
        except StopIteration:
            return False

        if i1 != i2:
            return False

    try:
        i2 = next(iter2)
    except StopIteration:
        return True

    return False
```

This has the advantage of working on any two sequences, at an obvious cost in complexity.

---

<sup>1</sup> I note there's an exception for sets and frozensets.  And no doubt a few others I'm not aware of.  The language designers are purists, except where it pays to be practical.

Comment: To compare two sequences, there's no need to jump through next/StopIteration hoops.
all(i1 == i2 for i1, i2 in itertools.izip_longest(iter1, iter2, fillvalue=object()))