# What are the best ways to compare the contents of two list-like objects?

Tags: python, polymorphism, idioms

When I have to compare the contents of two array-like objects -- for instance `list`s, `tuple`s or `collection.deque`s -- without regard for the type of the objects, I use

```
list(an_arrayish) == list(another_arrayish)
```

Is there any more idiomatic/faster/better way to achieve this?

Comment: Any chance of changing the title to "What is the fastest way..."? Casting both lists as tuples increases memory use, and I've never seen this presented as an idiomatic approach.

Comment: I'll change it to ask for the best ways as I'm equally interested in the fastest as in the most readable way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Compare it elementwise:

```
def compare(a,b):
    if len(a) != len(b):
        return False
    return all(i == j for i,j in itertools.izip(a,b))
```

For Python 3.x, use `zip` instead

Comment: Using the benchmark above, this gives times of around 9-10 seconds.

Comment: @minitech This is expected because Python loops are obviously much slower than C loops. But it will never blow up your memory because it do not require doubling the storage as tuple/list approach does. Also, it'll be better for lists of different sizes (or ones that differ in the first items)

Comment: minitech: Comparing two 1 million item lists takes 200ms on my machine. I'm not sure what you're doing that is taking so long.

Comment: @MatthewTrevor: Are you using 1,000,000 iterations? (`timeit`) If so, then the answer is "discount laptop". :)

Comment: I'm just using the `%timeit` magic function in IPython, so I'm not entirely sure how many iterations it tries by default.

Comment: You can omit the `len` check (or wrap it in `try...except TypeError`) and replace `izip` with `izip_longest` to make the comparison lazy, so that you can compare arbitrary iterables, like files.

Comment: This is the only method that works reliably. The others fail under some conditions. (I haven't investigated which exactly yet).

Answer (score 3):

Tuples appear to be faster:

```
tuple(an_arrayish) == tuple(another_arrayish)
```

Here's a quick benchmark:

```
>>> timeit.Timer('list(a) == list(b)', 'a, b = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5), (1, 2, 3, 4, 6)').timeit()
2.563981056213379
>>> timeit.Timer('list(a) == list(b)', 'a, b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 6]').timeit()
2.4739551544189453
>>> timeit.Timer('tuple(a) == tuple(b)', 'a, b = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5), (1, 2, 3, 4, 6)').timeit()
1.3630101680755615
>>> timeit.Timer('tuple(a) == tuple(b)', 'a, b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 6]').timeit()
1.475499153137207
```

Answer (score 0):

> Tuples and lists are compared lexicographically using comparison of
>   corresponding elements. This means that to compare equal, each element
>   must compare equal and the two sequences must be of the same type and
>   have the same length.

Seeing that we're not running into the convention some other languages use of "equality here means we are testing if these references refer to the same object in memory" I'd say sticking with the `==` equality test is the simplest way to accomplish this and therefore the best.

Comment: Other language's `==` does exist in Python, in the form of `is`.

Comment: @erik This is true. I wasn't arguing that it wasn't, simply that Python's `==` behavior wasn't in a lot of other languages short of writing code like `my_java_string.equals(your_java_string);` for reference variables. Since we have this (IMO) nicer `==` behavior, my vote goes to continuing to use it for the case you've outlined.

Comment: @Eric: > Other language's == does exist in Python, in the form of is < This is not true. Given two lists, l1 and l2, Python's `is` only tests only tests if l1 and l2 are the same object by testing their memory address. So `l1 is l2` returns True only if l1 and l2 occupy the same address. `l1 == l2` DOES exist in Python, but does a different functions. It is up to the individual class to define it by defining the `__eq__` method