# Why does "==" comparison return False even though tuple and list contain same values?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, tuples, operators

I tried following code:

```
T = ('a','b','c')
L = list(T)

print(T == L)         #Output: False
```

I ran PythonTutor for visualization and got:

[image]

Now it is clear to me why `T is L` returns `False`. But since `T,L` contain the exact same *values* for each *element*, I am confused why the `==` comparison returns `False`.

Comment: @roganjosh I do understand that, but the == operator compares the values of both the operands and checks for value equality, doesnt it?

Comment: Is `"3" == 3` True? Should it be?

Comment: If you really wanted to compare the two and ensure that each value of each iterable is true, then you should implement your own comparator by: `all(t == l for t, l in zip(T, L))`

Comment: Ok, so I think I got the "==" operator wrong. So it does pay attention to the types as well, not only the values! Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: I think this is a fair enough question to ask, since for example `3 == 3.0` in Python, and we all know what Javascript is like. At the end of the day the answer is just that that's the way it is - instances of container types do not normally consider themselves to be equal to instances of a different type. (You can always subclass list and tuple and override `__eq__`)

Comment: I definitely don't think it's an unreasonable question, I just posed it in a basic form :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: Why is comparison between lists and tuples not supported?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2345092/python-why-is-comparison-between-lists-and-tuples-not-supported)

Answer (score 0):

`('a','b','c') == ['a','b','c']` returns False because a comparison between a list and a tuple always returns False, regardless of their contents. This is documented at https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#value-comparisons:

> Sequences (instances of tuple, list, or range) can be compared only within each of their types, with the restriction that ranges do not support order comparison. **Equality comparison across these types results in inequality**, and ordering comparison across these types raises TypeError.

---